# How to access aggregate functions values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I am doing a predicition model in python for a football league. I just found the aggregate functions. Everything worked great until I encountered this problem : I am trying to compare some value of one column like :

```
'column1' : 'count'

#My code
final = dataset.groupby(['Home','Away'], as_index=False).agg({'HG': ['mean'], 'AG': ['mean', 'count']})
```

One idea of mine was to change type of column (maybe the value of 'count') but it didn't work.

What I am trying to do is check, in a function if there were more matches in this pair before, here is an example of output from 'final' dataframe:

```
        Home    Away            HG           AG
                            mean        mean    count

0   Astra   Bistrita    4.000000    0.000000    1
1   Astra   CFR Cluj    1.100000    2.100000    10
2   Astra   CS......    1.000000    1.000000    1
```

Where 'count' is times when there were matches in this formula ' Astra vs Bistrita ' happend just once in a few seasons.

I wanted to do something like this (and many more after I hop over this error) :

```
def functie(home, away):
    subset = final.loc[(final.Home==home)&(final.Away==away)]
    #print(subset['AG'].count)
    if (subset['AG'].count >= 1):
        print("It worked")

functie('Astra', 'Bistrita')
```

Here's the error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-2e7b6464c49d> in <module>
     92         print("It worked")
     93 
---> 94 functie('Astra', 'Bistrita')
     95 
     96 final.head(30)

<ipython-input-46-2e7b6464c49d> in functie(home, away)
     89     subset = final.loc[(final.Home==home)&(final.Away==away)]
     90     #print(subset['AG'].count)
---> 91     if (subset['AG'].count >= 1):
     92         print("It worked")
     93 

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int'
```

**EDIT:

If I call this :

```
subset = final.loc[(final.Home=='Astra')&(final.Away=='CFR Cluj')]
subset['AG'].count(axis = 0)
```

It gives me

```
mean     1
count    1
dtype: int64
```

Which is ok becasue it works as intended, it just counts how many rows I have if home team is 'Astra' and away team is 'CFR Cluj'. But I want to access the count column from AG, from 'final' dataframe.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking for. Can you show an example of the output you're trying to create? The subject of your question doesn't seem at all to match its contents.

Comment: You need to call your method: `subset['AG'].count()`

Comment: Ok. I added more info, I want in reality to do something if : 'count'  is > 3 ... else: do something else. I just want to check if there were similar games like this before and do something, if there were or were not. @Metropolis

Comment: Ok I edited again. Should be more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to get my answer and I am posting it here for others that have the same problem. Here is what I've done:

```
# group by home and away and get the mean from HomeGoals and AwayGoals
final = dataset.groupby(['Home','Away'], as_index=False).agg({'HG': ['mean'], 'AG': ['mean']})

#count all the matches where one HomeTeam encountered the same AwayTeam, by a random column, it will get the same 'count' for every column
total_matches = dataset.groupby(['Home','Away'], as_index=False).AvgA.transform('count') 

#set the column total_matches with total matches :)
dataset['total_matches'] = total_matches 

def functie(home, away):
    # get the results from big dataset where I have all the matches from 6-7 years 
    # and list all the 'Some Home Team' vs 'Some Away Team'
    subset = dataset.loc[(dataset.Home==home)&(dataset.Away==away)]
    
    #take the value of column 'total_matches' from first row, it's all the same on the nth 
    #row
    x = subset['total_matches'].iloc[0]
    if (x < 3):
        print("Less than three matches" , x)
    else:
        if(x >= 3):
            print("More than three matches" , x)

functie('Astra', 'CFR Cluj')

#gives the output 10

functie('Astra', 'Bistrita')

#gives the output 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`subset['AG'].count` is pandas' `count` method applied to `subset['AG']`. Since it's written without `()`, this gives you the method itself, not any of its results.

What you apparently want to do instead is to access one column of the `subset` dataframe. That dataframe has a MultiIndex on its columns, which means that you can access a single column with a tuple of the column names.

So in your code,

```py
subset['AG'].count
```

should be replaced with

```py
subset['AG', 'count']
```

This solves the ambiguity that in your version, `count` was interpreted as a method name, whereas you wanted it to mean the column name.

However, note that `subset['AG', 'count'] >= 1` will give you a Boolean Series, because every value of that column will be compared to 1. So you still need to think about what exactly the `if` condition should be.